# Cadence from BLE Device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, cadence

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         NSData *data = characteristic.value;
         uint8_t *array = (uint8_t*) data.bytes;

         cadenceValue = [CharacteristicReader readUInt8Value:&array];
         self.cadence.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", cadenceValue];
         });
}
```

How to get cadence from **bLE** (Bluetooth low energy) device in **swift 2**. I am unable to find exact code for this. For this `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` delegate method is called.

I have a code of nRF Toolbox but it is in **objective c** or **swift 3** but my project is in **swift 2**. I tried to call objective c method using bridging header but it was always returned 0 cadence.

Comment: What does the Swift 3 sample code look like?

Comment: Getting Error on bindMemory and pointee in swift 2


// on didUpdateValueForCharacteristic


let data = characteristic.value
var array = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(mutating: (data! as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: data!.count))
self.cadenceValue = NORCharacteristicReader.readUInt8Value(ptr: &array)

// Method.

static func readUInt8Value(ptr aPointer : inout UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> UInt8 {
    let val = aPointer.pointee
    aPointer = aPointer.successor()
    return val
}

@davidgyoung

Comment: @davidgyoung facing problem to convert above code in swift 2, Problem is with aPointer.pointee and bindMemory

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the definition of `CharacteristicReader`, but you might try:

```
[CharacteristicReader readUInt8Value:&array];
cadenceValue = Int(array[0])
self.cadence.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", cadenceValue];
```

The above assumes that the result of the call to readUInt8Value gets put into the array of `UInt8` objects, and the cadence value is in the first byte of the array.  You could also check if the proper value is in other bytes by trying `cadenceValue = Int(array[1])` or `cadenceValue = Int(array[2])`, etc.